# GetResourceAsStream not working on Websphere server

Tags: java, websphere, classloader

Application Server : IBM Websphere

Java 6

Issue :

Below is the folder structure of web application :

WEB-INF/libs/props/

The issue is below code is not working :

this.getClass().getResourceAsStream('/props'/+fileName) where fileName is a valid file name inside props folder of WEB-INF/lib/pros.

The class which is calling above method is inside a JAR and included in lib

The above call returns NULL.

The same set up works on tomcat with web application deployed in expanded mode integrated inside Inteliij IDE. On environment where this issue is coming , the application is deployed as ear
Please help as I  not able to get any clue on this

Comment: Are you running your application as a war file, or has it been expanded on disk?  What version of WebSphere?

Comment: It will be deployed as war. (It can be an ear also but not expanded) . I will let you know websphere version

Comment: Is this issue related with websphere class loading ? I am really getting clueless about this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The **jar files** under `WEB-INF/lib` are in the classpath. Not `WEB-INF/lib` itself.

The file should be in one of those jars, or under `WEB-INF/classes` (which is in the classpath)

Comment: As per the Java doc, getResourceAsStream will resolve file name with absolute path if fileName contains / , which is the case for me.Then the class loader which loaded the class from jar should be able to get this file name since it is absolute path.

Comment: getResourceAsStream() loads **resources** (not files) from the classpath (not the file system). WEB-INF/lib is not in the classpath.

Comment: Thanks a lot for explanation. I will move resource inside classes folder and try

Comment: There is still one question that remains. Why same set up works on tomcat with web application deployed as expanded. On another environment where this issue is coming, it is inside ear . So why it is working in first case?

Comment: It's strange . I have moved the resources to classes folder but same error is thrown. I am really getting clueless about this.

Comment: What is `this.getClass()`? Does it return a class that is part of the same webapp? (i.e. in the same war)?

Comment: Yes. It is a class in one of the Jars included in WEB-INF/lib

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help and time.